# How to find the right meaningful question to ask and finding duplicates fast!

Tags: support, asking-questions

I know there is a few duplicates but I want to narrow it down a bit more....

What is the etiquette in regard to asking questions, any pointers, tips? I know if the question is tagged as subjective it will be voted to close immediately - no questions asked based on the community feedback.

Also, how do you find duplicates fast? Despite a search functionality, it seems a bit slow having to wade to find the ones that match the question accurately or nearest when someone puts in a comment to say 'Duplicate...with an {url_to_nearest_question}', there must be some shortcut to achieve this.

Maybe, the limit to increase the number of questions (15, 30, 50 per page) might help instead of wading through pages.

Based on the feeling of the community, with consideration...due to the misunderstandings of the english language or misinterpretation, or even lack of english as it may not be their native tongue, any clear idea of guaranteeing that the question would be understood?

Like for example, posting a question that is vague or not clear or even ambiguous.

Thanks,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying the site's search box (or Google), I find that the best way to check for duplicates is to go the the **'Ask Question' page** and type in a clear, well-thought-out title. The **'Related Questions' suggestions** contain a really good list of candidates to look through.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the etiquette in regard to
>   asking questions, any pointers, tips?
>   I know if the question is tagged as
>   subjective it will be voted to close
>   immediately - no questions asked based
>   on the community feedback.

Try reading the official SO FAQ (here on meta). Lots of information there.

> Also, how do you find duplicates fast?
>   Despite a search functionality, it
>   seems a bit slow having to wade to
>   find the ones that match the question
>   accurately or nearest when someone
>   puts in a comment to say
>   'Duplicate...with an
>   {url_to_nearest_question}', there must
>   be some shortcut to achieve this.

SO's search engine is really bad compared to google's. Google `your question title site:stackoverflow.com`, you'll get much more relevant results.

> It would be nice to have the common
>   tags listed and grouped with the
>   answers you have posted on a prior
>   occastion, maybe, the limit to
>   increase the number of questions (15,
>   30, 50 per page) or select a tag from
>   dropdown box and see the answers that
>   was posted.

I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean here.

> Based on the feeling of the community,
>   with consideration...due to the
>   misunderstandings of the english
>   language or misinterpretation, or even
>   lack of english as it may not be their
>   native tongue, any clear idea of
>   guaranteeing that the question would
>   be understood?

Are you asking how to ask a question and have the guarantee to be understood if the person who asks it doesn't speak English? If yes the answer is "use magic".

Comment: @Koper: Thanks for your answer, when I mentioned about common tags, if the common tags are clicked on, you should be able to see your answers posted instead of all questions associated with that tag. When you view the main so page, there's the option of 15/30/50 questions per page, this is also applicable to your own page where you can see what questions you have posted.

Comment: @Koper: Actually, in hindsight the tags are at the bottom of the page - that I did not realize they were clickable, I thought they provided x amount of answers for the tag only....sorry... I'll edit my question accordingly to the stupid mess up I made there... sorry...